# Linked list insertion sort

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I'm not very advanced in the sorting part of programming yet, so I was looking for some help with my algorithm.

```
void sortList()
{
    Item_PTR tmpNxt = current->nextItem;
    Item_PTR tmpPTR = current;
    int a, tmp;

    while(tmpNxt != NULL)
    {   
        a = tmpPTR->value;
        while(tmpNxt != tmpPTR && tmpNxt->value < a)
        {
            tmp = a;
            tmpPTR->value = tmpNxt->value;
            tmpNxt->value = tmp;
            tmpPTR = tmpPTR->nextItem;
        }
        tmpPTR = current;   
        tmpNxt = tmpNxt->nextItem;
    }

}
```

The list state before sorting: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
after sorting: 1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

I'm not sure why...I've played computer a lot on paper and I feel like it should work...but maybe other eyes will spot the problem.

Current is a global pointer that will always have the location of the first/ top element in the list.

Comment: Do you mean "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1" is the state of the list before sorting and "1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2" the state after sorting?

Comment: yes ^^; sorry i'll make that clear in the first post.

Comment: Why don't you step it through with a debugger?

Comment: using a txt editor and terminal... :\

Comment: Use gdb: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ It's a command line debugger, and if you're on linux it's probably already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the function `sortList()` is **not** changing `current`, the "global"
variable denoting the list head.

Please don't use a global variable, and certainly not for a linked list head. (What will you do when you need *two* lists?)

I would redesign the `sortList()` function to either one of the following:

```
/* sort the list pointed to by phead and return the new head after sorting */
Item_PTR sortList( Item_PTR phead );

/* sort the list pointed to by *pphead */
void sortList( Item_PTR * pphead );
```

Also, make yourself familiar (even if you can't use them in the immediate project) to the interface of C++ Standard Library for lists, `std::list` [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)

Comment: I can't use the library ;) because it is a special project. I'm using tmpPTR to compare all numbers up to tmpNxt. All I'm doing with current is using it to reset the tmpPTR to the top of the list so it can compare all up to the tmpNxt.

Comment: Yes, I figured that, hence I said make yourself familiar :-). Some more suggestions: (1) Write a function to print, say `printList()`, the contents of the list. (2) use sortList for all combinations of three-element lists [i.e. {1 2 3}, {1 3 2}, {2 1 3} ..} (3) Call `printList()` both before and after the call to `sortList()`. Important: Whenever the first element in the list is not the minimum one, its position after sorting is required to change, but unless `current` is updated, that change won't come into effect.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the changes suggested by @Arun Saha, there seems to be some logical mistake (not updating a value after swapping), that's why the list os not even printing in sorted order even inside the sort function. Following code should solve that.

```
void sortList()
{
    Item_PTR tmpNxt = current->nextItem;
    Item_PTR tmpPTR = current;

    while(tmpNxt != NULL)
    {   
        while(tmpNxt != tmpPTR && tmpNxt->value < tmpPTR->value)
        {
            int tmp = tmpPTR->value;
            tmpPTR->value = tmpNxt->value;
            tmpNxt->value = tmp;
            tmpPTR = tmpPTR->nextItem;
        }
        tmpPTR = current;   
        tmpNxt = tmpNxt->nextItem;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         **Java code for insertion sort of linked list**





    package LinkedList;

/**
 * Created by dheeraj on 5/1/15.
 */
public class InsertionSortLinkedList {

    private static final class Node {
        int value;
        Node next;

        public Node(int d) {
            value = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    private Node root;
    private Node sortedHead;

    private void addData(int data) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(data);
        } else {
            Node temp = new Node(data);
            temp.next = root;
            root = temp;
        }
    }

    private void printList() {
        Node temp = root;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.value + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void printSortedList() {
        Node temp = sortedHead;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.value + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void insertionSort() {
        Node outer = root;
        Node resultRoot = null;
        if (outer == null) {
            return;
        }
        while (outer != null) {
            if (resultRoot == null) {
                //System.out.println("null");
                resultRoot = new Node(outer.value);
            } else {
                Node t = resultRoot;
                if (outer.value < t.value) {
                    //current outer is smallest
                    //System.out.println("smallest");
                    Node temp = new Node(outer.value);
                    temp.next = t;
                    resultRoot = temp;
                } else {
                    boolean broken = false;
                    while (t.next != null) {
                        if (t.value < outer.value && outer.value <= t.next.value) {
                            Node temp = new Node(outer.value);
                            temp.next = t.next;
                            t.next = temp;
                            broken = true;
                            //System.out.println("middle");
                            break;
                        }
                        //
                        t = t.next;
                    }
                    if (!broken) {
                        //current outer is greatest
                        //System.out.println("largest");
                        t.next = new Node(outer.value);
                    }
                }
            }
            outer = outer.next;
        }
        sortedHead = resultRoot;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InsertionSortLinkedList insertionSortLinkedList = new InsertionSortLinkedList();
        insertionSortLinkedList.addData(5);
        insertionSortLinkedList.addData(30);
        insertionSortLinkedList.addData(1);
        insertionSortLinkedList.addData(18);
        insertionSortLinkedList.addData(19);

        insertionSortLinkedList.printList();
        insertionSortLinkedList.insertionSort();
        insertionSortLinkedList.printSortedList();
    }
}
```