# Trying to understand how the linked list properties work when you want to return the head node

Tags: linked-list

Lets say you are reading in a string into your linked list function but each node stores only one char at a time.

Now as you go through the nodes using your current and temp nodes(leaving your head node untouched) all while comparing everything to your head node for organization purposes.

and you return your head node...does it only return one letter from the string(this is what confuses me) or does it print out all of the letters from each node that was created?

Comment: this depends on your implementation of the function.. do you have code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return the head of a linked list, you are returning the **entire list**. The caller that receives the returned head will know that it can perform any linked list related operations to the list. In other words, the head is the representation of a linked list.

Comment: so to clarify..i am passing a string "bob" char by char within each node...and as i compare the current node to the head node i am re arranging the order of the letters so that once i return the head node it will read "bbo"

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to sort the characters in a string. I don't quit get it why you want to do it with linked list. But if you have to do that way, you may want to look at bubble sort of linked lists here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5526798/1895314. It's the simplest one, and from your description, it should be your answer.